# I would like to use the span slider from Qxt without having to install it. Is this possible?

Tags: c++, qt

I stumbled across a [widget](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/src/696423b68972fc9edae318558b8ce26dc187cc40/src/widgets/qxtspanslider.cpp?at=master) that provides you with a slider with two handles so you can select a range between an upper and lower limit.

I would like to use it without having to install all of Qxt though, since I am pretty sure this is the only thing that I need.

How can I deal with qxt_p() in order to use this widget as a standalone?

Comment: Just pick all the widgets you want ? You are free to use, modify and distribute the source code thanks to the licence. Moreover, it is said that libqxt is not maintained anymore so "We recommend that you pick out the parts you want instead of using the entire libqxt.". So pick and modify the source to remove dependencies if any even if it is not as simple to do as to say.

Comment: My issue is of curse not on the license, I never intended using it without giving credit. But the whole library is too big and it seemed a waste when I only needed one class. As I said in the question though I encountered some problems using it as a standalone, namely the call to qxt_d().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following in the main class:

```
private:
  QxtSpanSliderPrivate* d_ptr;
  friend class QxtSpanSliderPrivate;
```

And in the following in the private class:

```
private:
  QxtSpanSlider* q_ptr;
  friend class QxtSpanSlider;
```

Also you should remove Qwt macros usage and replace `qxt_d()` and `qxt_q()` with direct access to `q_ptr` and `d_ptr`.

Each constructor of the main class should initialize both pointers:

```
QxtSpanSlider::QxtSpanSlider(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget* parent) :
  QSlider(orientation, parent), 
  d_ptr(new QxtSpanSliderPrivate())
{
  d_ptr->q_ptr = this;
  //...
}
```

In case I forgot something, [here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/Riateche/27e36977f7d5ea72cf4f). This code allowed me to successfully use `QxtSpanSlider` in Qt5.

Comment: Also since it's good knowing what you are doing I would also recommend reading this [link](https://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++) from the KDE tech base.

Comment: @Pavel Strakhov I am getting the error:                               qxtspanslider.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QSlider::initStyleOption(class QStyleOptionSlider *)const " (?initStyleOption@QSlider@@QEBAXPEAVQStyleOptionSlider@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl QxtSpanSliderPrivate::initStyleOption(class QStyleOptionSlider *,enum QxtSpanSlider::SpanHandle)const " (?initStyleOption@QxtSpanSliderPrivate@@QEBAXPEAVQStyleOptionSlider@@W4SpanHandle@QxtSpanSlider@@@Z)