# Double slider / slider with two thumbs Qt

Tags: c++, qt, slider, qwidget

I am using Qt 5.5.1 and MSVC2013. I need a custom double slider like here:

[image]

This example is implemented in a library called [ctk](https://github.com/commontk/CTK). I can not use the library because it does only support Qt 4. Therefore I want to use the `ctkDoubleRangeSlider.h` and `ctkDoubleRangeSlider.cpp` from those libraries for creating a self standing double slider widget. A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620816/i-would-like-to-use-the-span-slider-from-qxt-without-having-to-install-it-is-th), using Qxt, but I could not make it run.

Can someone help me with this? I tried it for a whole day and could not make it happen.