# Porting range-slider widget to PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, slider, pyqt5

I am currently in need for a range slider (a slider where I can set up a min and a max value). I found two related questions [Range slider in Qt (two handles in a QSlider)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361885/range-slider-in-qt-two-handles-in-a-qslider) and [Why RangeSlider is available in QtQuick and not as standard Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838789/why-rangeslider-is-available-in-qtquick-and-not-as-standard-widget?noredirect=1&lq=1) but neither of them is written in python3 and I am not very familiar with C++.

I found this perfect github tool https://github.com/rsgalloway/qrangeslider but it is unfortunately written for PyQt4 and I am using PyQt5.

I am planning to reformat this github source with PyQt5 bindings but before doing so I want to know if anyone has done it before so I could save time?
Or if anyone has a different solution, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Below is a PyQt5 port of the [QRangeSlider widget](https://github.com/rsgalloway/qrangeslider). For the sake of brevity, I have removed all comments, doc-strings, assert statements, etc. It seems to work okay with both Python 2 and Python 3, but I haven't really tested it much.

***qrangeslider.py***:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

__all__ = ['QRangeSlider']

DEFAULT_CSS = """
QRangeSlider * {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
QRangeSlider #Head {
    background: #222;
}
QRangeSlider #Span {
    background: #393;
}
QRangeSlider #Span:active {
    background: #282;
}
QRangeSlider #Tail {
    background: #222;
}
QRangeSlider > QSplitter::handle {
    background: #393;
}
QRangeSlider > QSplitter::handle:vertical {
    height: 4px;
}
QRangeSlider > QSplitter::handle:pressed {
    background: #ca5;
}
"""

def scale(val, src, dst):
    return int(((val - src[0]) / float(src[1]-src[0])) * (dst[1]-dst[0]) + dst[0])


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("QRangeSlider")
        Form.resize(300, 30)
        Form.setStyleSheet(DEFAULT_CSS)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self._splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(Form)
        self._splitter.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self._splitter.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self._splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self._splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self._head = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self._splitter)
        self._head.setTitle("")
        self._head.setObjectName("Head")
        self._handle = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self._splitter)
        self._handle.setTitle("")
        self._handle.setObjectName("Span")
        self._tail = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self._splitter)
        self._tail.setTitle("")
        self._tail.setObjectName("Tail")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self._splitter, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("QRangeSlider", "QRangeSlider"))


class Element(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        super(Element, self).__init__(parent)
        self.main = main

    def setStyleSheet(self, style):
        self.parent().setStyleSheet(style)

    def textColor(self):
        return getattr(self, '__textColor', QtGui.QColor(125, 125, 125))

    def setTextColor(self, color):
        if type(color) == tuple and len(color) == 3:
            color = QtGui.QColor(color[0], color[1], color[2])
        elif type(color) == int:
            color = QtGui.QColor(color, color, color)
        setattr(self, '__textColor', color)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        if self.main.drawValues():
            self.drawText(event, qp)
        qp.end()


class Head(Element):
    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        super(Head, self).__init__(parent, main)

    def drawText(self, event, qp):
        qp.setPen(self.textColor())
        qp.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 10))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, str(self.main.min()))


class Tail(Element):
    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        super(Tail, self).__init__(parent, main)

    def drawText(self, event, qp):
        qp.setPen(self.textColor())
        qp.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 10))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignRight, str(self.main.max()))


class Handle(Element):
    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        super(Handle, self).__init__(parent, main)

    def drawText(self, event, qp):
        qp.setPen(self.textColor())
        qp.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 10))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, str(self.main.start()))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignRight, str(self.main.end()))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        mx = event.globalX()
        _mx = getattr(self, '__mx', None)
        if not _mx:
            setattr(self, '__mx', mx)
            dx = 0
        else:
            dx = mx - _mx
        setattr(self, '__mx', mx)
        if dx == 0:
            event.ignore()
            return
        elif dx > 0:
            dx = 1
        elif dx < 0:
            dx = -1
        s = self.main.start() + dx
        e = self.main.end() + dx
        if s >= self.main.min() and e <= self.main.max():
            self.main.setRange(s, e)


class QRangeSlider(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    endValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    maxValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    minValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    startValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    minValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    maxValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    startValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    endValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    _SPLIT_START = 1
    _SPLIT_END = 2

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QRangeSlider, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setMouseTracking(False)
        self._splitter.splitterMoved.connect(self._handleMoveSplitter)
        self._head_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self._head_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self._head_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self._head.setLayout(self._head_layout)
        self.head = Head(self._head, main=self)
        self._head_layout.addWidget(self.head)
        self._handle_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self._handle_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self._handle_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self._handle.setLayout(self._handle_layout)
        self.handle = Handle(self._handle, main=self)
        self.handle.setTextColor((150, 255, 150))
        self._handle_layout.addWidget(self.handle)
        self._tail_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self._tail_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self._tail_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self._tail.setLayout(self._tail_layout)
        self.tail = Tail(self._tail, main=self)
        self._tail_layout.addWidget(self.tail)
        self.setMin(0)
        self.setMax(99)
        self.setStart(0)
        self.setEnd(99)
        self.setDrawValues(True)

    def min(self):
        return getattr(self, '__min', None)

    def max(self):
        return getattr(self, '__max', None)

    def setMin(self, value):
        setattr(self, '__min', value)
        self.minValueChanged.emit(value)

    def setMax(self, value):
        setattr(self, '__max', value)
        self.maxValueChanged.emit(value)

    def start(self):
        return getattr(self, '__start', None)

    def end(self):
        return getattr(self, '__end', None)

    def _setStart(self, value):
        setattr(self, '__start', value)
        self.startValueChanged.emit(value)

    def setStart(self, value):
        v = self._valueToPos(value)
        self._splitter.splitterMoved.disconnect()
        self._splitter.moveSplitter(v, self._SPLIT_START)
        self._splitter.splitterMoved.connect(self._handleMoveSplitter)
        self._setStart(value)

    def _setEnd(self, value):
        setattr(self, '__end', value)
        self.endValueChanged.emit(value)

    def setEnd(self, value):
        v = self._valueToPos(value)
        self._splitter.splitterMoved.disconnect()
        self._splitter.moveSplitter(v, self._SPLIT_END)
        self._splitter.splitterMoved.connect(self._handleMoveSplitter)
        self._setEnd(value)

    def drawValues(self):
        return getattr(self, '__drawValues', None)

    def setDrawValues(self, draw):
        setattr(self, '__drawValues', draw)

    def getRange(self):
        return (self.start(), self.end())

    def setRange(self, start, end):
        self.setStart(start)
        self.setEnd(end)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
            s = self.start()-1
            e = self.end()-1
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
            s = self.start()+1
            e = self.end()+1
        else:
            event.ignore()
            return
        event.accept()
        if s >= self.min() and e <= self.max():
            self.setRange(s, e)

    def setBackgroundStyle(self, style):
        self._tail.setStyleSheet(style)
        self._head.setStyleSheet(style)

    def setSpanStyle(self, style):
        self._handle.setStyleSheet(style)

    def _valueToPos(self, value):
        return scale(value, (self.min(), self.max()), (0, self.width()))

    def _posToValue(self, xpos):
        return scale(xpos, (0, self.width()), (self.min(), self.max()))

    def _handleMoveSplitter(self, xpos, index):
        hw = self._splitter.handleWidth()
        def _lockWidth(widget):
            width = widget.size().width()
            widget.setMinimumWidth(width)
            widget.setMaximumWidth(width)
        def _unlockWidth(widget):
            widget.setMinimumWidth(0)
            widget.setMaximumWidth(16777215)
        if index == self._SPLIT_START:
            v = self._posToValue(xpos)
            _lockWidth(self._tail)
            if v >= self.end():
                return
            offset = -20
            w = xpos + offset
            self._setStart(v)
        elif index == self._SPLIT_END:
            v = self._posToValue(xpos + 2 * hw)
            _lockWidth(self._head)
            if v <= self.start():
                return
            offset = -40
            w = self.width() - xpos + offset
            self._setEnd(v)
        _unlockWidth(self._tail)
        _unlockWidth(self._head)
        _unlockWidth(self._handle)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    rs = QRangeSlider()
    rs.show()
    rs.setRange(15, 35)
    rs.setBackgroundStyle('background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #222, stop:1 #333);')
    rs.handle.setStyleSheet('background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #282, stop:1 #393);')
    app.exec_()
```

If you want to run the [examples](https://github.com/rsgalloway/QRangeSlider/blob/master/examples.py), you just need to change the following code block (at the top of the file):

***examples.py***:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from qrangeslider import QRangeSlider

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

...
```

Comment: @mangovn See the examples in the PyQt docs: [Using Qt Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). Once you have your main window set up like that, you can add whatever widgets you like. Alternatively, you could use widget promotion to add it via Qt Designer (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42076247/984421) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46023667/984421)).

Answer (score 7):

Here is a PySide2 example with a native look and feels:

[image: RangeSlider]

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

import sys


class RangeSlider(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.first_position = 1
        self.second_position = 8

        self.opt = QStyleOptionSlider()
        self.opt.minimum = 0
        self.opt.maximum = 10

        self.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksAbove)
        self.setTickInterval(1)

        self.setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Slider)
        )

    def setRangeLimit(self, minimum: int, maximum: int):
        self.opt.minimum = minimum
        self.opt.maximum = maximum

    def setRange(self, start: int, end: int):
        self.first_position = start
        self.second_position = end

    def getRange(self):
        return (self.first_position, self.second_position)

    def setTickPosition(self, position: QSlider.TickPosition):
        self.opt.tickPosition = position

    def setTickInterval(self, ti: int):
        self.opt.tickInterval = ti

    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent):

        painter = QPainter(self)

        # Draw rule
        self.opt.initFrom(self)
        self.opt.rect = self.rect()
        self.opt.sliderPosition = 0
        self.opt.subControls = QStyle.SC_SliderGroove | QStyle.SC_SliderTickmarks

        #   Draw GROOVE
        self.style().drawComplexControl(QStyle.CC_Slider, self.opt, painter)

        #  Draw INTERVAL

        color = self.palette().color(QPalette.Highlight)
        color.setAlpha(160)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(color))
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        self.opt.sliderPosition = self.first_position
        x_left_handle = (
            self.style()
            .subControlRect(QStyle.CC_Slider, self.opt, QStyle.SC_SliderHandle)
            .right()
        )

        self.opt.sliderPosition = self.second_position
        x_right_handle = (
            self.style()
            .subControlRect(QStyle.CC_Slider, self.opt, QStyle.SC_SliderHandle)
            .left()
        )

        groove_rect = self.style().subControlRect(
            QStyle.CC_Slider, self.opt, QStyle.SC_SliderGroove
        )

        selection = QRect(
            x_left_handle,
            groove_rect.y(),
            x_right_handle - x_left_handle,
            groove_rect.height(),
        ).adjusted(-1, 1, 1, -1)

        painter.drawRect(selection)

        # Draw first handle

        self.opt.subControls = QStyle.SC_SliderHandle
        self.opt.sliderPosition = self.first_position
        self.style().drawComplexControl(QStyle.CC_Slider, self.opt, painter)

        # Draw second handle
        self.opt.sliderPosition = self.second_position
        self.style().drawComplexControl(QStyle.CC_Slider, self.opt, painter)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):

        self.opt.sliderPosition = self.first_position
        self._first_sc = self.style().hitTestComplexControl(
            QStyle.CC_Slider, self.opt, event.pos(), self
        )

        self.opt.sliderPosition = self.second_position
        self._second_sc = self.style().hitTestComplexControl(
            QStyle.CC_Slider, self.opt, event.pos(), self
        )

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):

        distance = self.opt.maximum - self.opt.minimum

        pos = self.style().sliderValueFromPosition(
            0, distance, event.pos().x(), self.rect().width()
        )

        if self._first_sc == QStyle.SC_SliderHandle:
            if pos <= self.second_position:
                self.first_position = pos
                self.update()
                return

        if self._second_sc == QStyle.SC_SliderHandle:
            if pos >= self.first_position:
                self.second_position = pos
                self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        """ override """
        SliderLength = 84
        TickSpace = 5

        w = SliderLength
        h = self.style().pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_SliderThickness, self.opt, self)

        if (
            self.opt.tickPosition & QSlider.TicksAbove
            or self.opt.tickPosition & QSlider.TicksBelow
        ):
            h += TickSpace

        return (
            self.style()
            .sizeFromContents(QStyle.CT_Slider, self.opt, QSize(w, h), self)
            .expandedTo(QApplication.globalStrut())
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = RangeSlider()
    w.show()

    # q = QSlider()
    # q.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: This class could inherit from QSlider to have signals like valuechanged available

Comment: How can I make it vertical?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, @ekhumoro's implementation has a bug where the scale limit is set wrong when you try drag the slider to its upper limit, due to the slider width.

I fixed it by changing the following;

```
v = self._posToValue(xpos)
```

to;

```
if index == 1:
    v = self._posToValue(xpos)
elif index == 2:
    v = self._posToValue(xpos+hw)
```

Comment: The bug is in the original code, rather than my implementation. But anyway, your proposed fix isn't correct, since the displayed value still doesn't match the maximum at the limit. I have now updated my answer with a better fix.