# Using drawComplexControl to retrieve QSliderHandle image

Tags: c++, qt, qslider, qstyle

Today I was trying to take a picture of the `QSlider` handle in order to use it in an adpated `QSlider` widget with two handles.

This is somewhat similar to the following question: [Range slider in Qt (two handles in a QSlider)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17361885/5762796)

For a full fledged solution I can not use a simple image files. I tried to create the image of the `QSlider` by using the `drawComplexControl` function, but it leaves me basically with a black image.

What I'm doing wrong here? It seems so simple to me, but it is just not working.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyleOptionSlider>

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto slider = new QSlider;
    slider->setOrientation(Qt::Orientation::Horizontal);
    slider->show();

    auto btn = new QPushButton("Create Image");
    QObject::connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [&] {
        auto style = QApplication::style();
        QStyleOptionSlider sliderOptions;
        QPixmap pix(slider->size());
        auto painter = new QPainter();
        painter->begin(&pix);
        style->drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_Slider, &sliderOptions, painter, slider);

        pix.save("SliderImage.png");
        auto handleRect = style->subControlRect(QStyle::ComplexControl::CC_Slider, &sliderOptions, QStyle::SubControl::SC_SliderHandle, slider);
        QPixmap handlePix = pix.copy(handleRect);
        handlePix.save("SliderHandleImage.png");

        painter->end();
    });
    btn->show();
    app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple. I just forgot to add:

```
sliderOption.initFrom(slider);
```